# “In” or “of” for a location?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Would I say “Human Services *in* New York” or “Human Services *of* New York” if the Human Services serves and is located in New York but is not actually owned or governed by New York?

Comment: This is not a real question until prior efforts made to research the answer are added to it.

Answer (score 3):

When speaking of their physical location, you would say Human Services **in** New York.

When speaking of their service coverage, you would say Human Services **for** New York.

When speaking of who owns or operates them, you would say Human Services **of** New York.  (This generally implies that New York runs the services on behalf of its employees or citizens.  Alternatively, if you wanted to emphasize who provides the services, you could say Human Services **by** New York, which implies that other people besides New Yorkers can take advantage of the services.)